# Is the series suggesting that there were two attackers?

Tags: ending, unbelievable

The Netflix series "Unbelievable" follows a story of Marie, who was charged with lying about being raped and the two detectives, who follow a case of a serial rapist. During the series, after interviewing other victims, detectives  Grace Rasmussen and Karen Duvall notice a distinctive pattern regarding the attacker's behaviour during and after the assault:

> Victims were attacked multiple times over a period of hours, were forced to dress up and to shower afterwards.

In contrast, the attack on Marie was slightly different:

> It was relatively fast (15 minutes) and she was left tied down on the bed.

In the case of Marie, the attacker even mentions that "it wasn't as good as I've imagined".

At the end of the series

> Police have arrested the suspect and found the evidence of the crime - photos and stolen underwear. The suspect pleads guilty and he gets sentenced - however, he was sharing the house with **his brother** and the DNA evidence was at best pointing to a family, not a single person.

While there is no doubt, that the convicted man committed most of the crimes, is the series trying to suggest that his brother could be involved in Marie's case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marie's rape was his first one, back in 2008. The rapist's modus operandi wasn't that evolved back then, and in his interview with the FBI detective he even says that he expected to get caught based on the evidence he left behind. He became more careful afterwards.

Note that the series is based on real events, which you can read about here: https://www.themarshallproject.org/2015/12/16/an-unbelievable-story-of-rape .

Comment: Oh, I wasn't paying attention to the dates of the attacks, I always thought that Marie was one of the latest victims, not the first one.